# Gradle: configuration runtime declares a dependency on configuration default which is not declared in the module descriptor for

Tags: java, gradle, repository, ivy

Can you tell me why when I run gradle I get this error:

```
Error:Module version trestGradle:trestGradle:1.0-SNAPSHOT, 
configuration 'runtime' declares a dependency on 
configuration 'default' which is not declared in the module 
descriptor for it.develop:myLib:1.0.0"
```

What is needed to be declared on the ivy.xml (module descriptor)?

- MyLib is on an internal ivy repository
- I checked:credentials, ivy url and the pattern

build.gradle:

```
group 'trestGrad'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5

configurations {
    compile
}

repositories {
    ivy {
        url = 'http://example.com/artifactory/cst'
        credentials {
            username = "user"
            password = "pass123"
        }
        layout('pattern') {
            // Pattern to resolve Ivy descriptor files.
            ivy '[organization]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/ivy.xml'
            // Pattern to resolve files.
            artifact '[organization]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[module].[ext]'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile "it.develop:myLib:1.0.0"
}
```

Comment: You need to specify the myLIb configuration. Its ivy.xml likely references default which gradle doesn't understand. You need to look at it and see which configuration you need and specify that in your dependencies

Comment: java plugin already adds the `compile` configuration. Not sure why you're explicitly adding it again..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/dependencies-failing-to-resolve-due-to-configuration-dependencies/1617).

You need to specify the configuration for your dependency. Failing which ivy assumes `default` configuration and hence your error message.

Comment: **compile group: "it.develop", name: "myLib", version: "1.0.0",  configuration: "compile"**  *It worked!  Thanks*

Comment: I have already tried but i have received this message: "Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score."